# Image break text inside <p>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a simple rpg form and stuff, but here's my problem:
http://gyazo.com/ed68206c6bcf37609a8700c981919ad9

I need the text on the image (the black box) goes "around" the image, but, since the image is on a different "hierarchy", it just not seem to work:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    ///Here's de image
    <div class="panel-title" style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color: black; float:left; margin:20px">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="margin-left: 200px; position">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="height:40px">
            <li class="active"><a href="#pHistoriaDiv" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Historia</a>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#pPersonaDiv" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Personalidade</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="pHistoriaDiv" class="tab-pane fade active in">
                <h4></h4>

                //here is the <p> with the text to go around
                <p id="pHistoria" style="margin-left:5px; overflow: hidden;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="pPersonaDiv" class="tab-pane fade active in">
                <h4></h4>
                <p id="pPersona" style="margin-left:5px; overflow: hidden;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since i'm using bootstrap, i's useless to post the CSS because its too damn big, but I can happily edit with anything you guys need to help.

Any clues?? 
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is the image the black box? There's no image tag in your example... Can't you move the image into `tab-content`?

Comment: Yes, its the black box, sorry I forgot to mention :P.
The 'image' must be outside so the tabs work. Each tab is a Div ins a DIV inside the 'tab-content'.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the image appears in a separate div and because of bootstrap the text won't naturally wrap around the image.

I have moved the image/black box to your div, now the text should wrap around your image.

```
    /// Here is the nav panel
    <div class="panel-body" style="margin-left: 200px;">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="height:40px">
            <li class="active"><a href="#pHistoriaDiv" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Historia</a>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#pPersonaDiv" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Personalidade</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    /// Here is the Historia Tab

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="pHistoriaDiv" class="tab-pane fade active in">

        ///Here's the image - aligns to the left with the text wrapping around
        <div class="panel-title" style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color: black; float:left; margin:20px"></div>

                //here is the <p> with the text to go around
                <p id="pHistoria" style="margin-left:5px; overflow: hidden;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                </p>
            </div>


            <div id="pPersonaDiv" class="tab-pane fade active in">
                <h4></h4>
                <p id="pPersona" style="margin-left:5px; overflow: hidden;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Already tried this. BY doing that, the image will be inside the tabs on the image. It must be outside.